# Is it possible to disable running average calculation in tf.layers.batch_normalization?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, batch-normalization

Is it possible to disable running average calculation in [tf.layers.batch_normalization](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/layers/batch_normalization)? i.e. I want BN work the same for training and testing, estimating stats only on input tensor.

According to this equation momentum = 1.0 is sufficient for this behaviour?

`x_new_est = (1-momentum) * x_est + momentum * (x_t)`

or/and setting training=True in training and inference is sufficient?

> training: Either a Python boolean, or a TensorFlow boolean scalar
>   tensor (e.g. a placeholder). Whether to return the output in training
>   mode (normalized with statistics of the current batch) or in inference
>   mode (normalized with moving statistics). NOTE: make sure to set this
>   parameter correctly, or else your training/inference will not work
>   properly.

Seems this is possible in PyTorch
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.BatchNorm2d

> If track_running_stats is set to False, this layer then does not keep
>   running estimates, and batch statistics are instead used during
>   evaluation time as well.

Answer (score 0):

[Yes](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.0/tensorflow/python/layers/normalization.py#L252): `tf.layers.batch_normalization(..., training=True)`.

[Same deal](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/1cf0898dd4331baf93fe77205550f2c2e6c90ee5/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/normalization.py#L112) for `tf.keras.layers.batch_normalization`.

Note that with `training=True` fixed permanently, you can set `trainable=False` for a slight speedup, as it merely refers to updating the running EMA statistics (inference-mode). Also note that inferencing in `training=True` will render predictions batch-sample dependent - i.e. if you were to change *some* samples in the same batch, you'll get a different prediction for *all* samples.

Lastly, no, `momentum=1` is **not equivalent** to using BN in train mode, as all it does is fix `running_mean=0`, `running_var=1`, so inputs to BN will undergo identity transform: `(inputs - 0) / 1` - whereas in train mode, `inputs` are scaled according to statistics of `inputs` to get zero-mean and unit-variance. If `trainable=True`, then trained `gamma` and `beta` will apply afterwards for a linear transform. See Keras equivalent source code for [training](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/7a39b6c62d43c25472b2c2476bd2a8983ae4f682/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py#L2291) and [inference](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/normalization.py#L144) BN input processing.